# How to use typeahead.js with a large database

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, typeahead.js

I have a large database of 10,000 addresses and 5,000 people.

I want to let users search the database for either an address or a user. I'd like to use Twitter's typeahead to suggest results as they enter text.

See the NBA example here: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples.

I understand that prefetching 15,000 items would not be optimal from a speed and load standpoint. What would be a better way to try and achieve this?

Comment: `remote` is what you need. Check the last 2 examples

Comment: Just an idea, just chose a minimum amount of characters and then launch the typeahead funcitonality with  only the datas matching the reasearch field. This way you won't have 15000 items. But not sure if it won't be heavier if the user is some sort of a research maniac.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Since no one made any answer, I will go ahead with my suggestion then.

I think the best fit for your big database is using `remote` with `typeahead.js`. Quick example:

```
$('#user-search').typeahead({
    name: 'user-search',
    remote: '/search.php?query=%QUERY' // you can change anything but %QUERY
});
```

What it does is when you type characters in the `input#user-search` it will send AJAX request to the page `search.php` with query as the content of the input.

On `search.php` you can catch this query and look it up in your DB:

```
$query = $_GET['query'].'%'; // add % for LIKE query later

// do query
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username LIKE = :query');
$stmt->bindParam(':query', $query, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

// populate results
$results = array();
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) as $row) {
    $results[] = $row;
}

// and return to typeahead
return json_encode($results);
```

Of course since your DB is quite big, you should optimize your SQL query to query faster, maybe cache the result, etc.

On the typeahead side, to reduce load to query DB, you can specify `minLength` or `limit`:

```
$('#user-search').typeahead({
    name: 'user-search',
    remote: '/search.php?query=%QUERY',
    minLength: 3, // send AJAX request only after user type in at least 3 characters
    limit: 10 // limit to show only 10 results
});
```

So it doesn't really matter how big your DB is, this approach should work nicely.

This is an example in PHP but of course it should be the same for whatever backend you have. Hope you get the basic idea.

Comment: Did you look into Bloodhound?
I'm trying to wedge typeahed, knockout, and bloodhound into my head.
Although from what I've seen of Bloodhound it can just hook into typeahead.

Comment: How would you do this Ruby?

Comment: @Jackson_Sandland that depends on the framework you are using, and I guess you should open a new question with tag Ruby for that

Comment: Note, for remote you now have to use BloodHound.

Comment: Does this search in "real time"?  Or do the database results only get loaded at page load?  So, for example, if an entry was added to the database, would it immediately be available for the user?

Comment: The whole point of this "remote" is there is an AJAX request to your backend every time user searches something so the result is always latest result from your DB.