# typeahead.js and remote php

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I use typeahead.js with Local data source and worked, but when i try to collect data from remote url i have no luck this is my code :

```js
$('#keyword').typeahead({
    minLength: 3,
    remote: 'http://example.com/includes/search.php?g=%QUERY',
    limit: 10
});
```

and this is my php code :

```php
<? PHP
    $qsrc = mysql_query("SELECT `state_id` AS `all_id`,`name` AS `names`, MATCH(name) AGAINST('".$_REQUEST('g')."') AS `score` FROM `_state` WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('".$_REQUEST('g')."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY `score` DESC");
    $arr = array();
    while ($rsrc = mysql_fetch_assoc($qsrc)) {
        $arr[] = array('id' = > $rsrc['all_id'], 'name' = > $rsrc['names']);
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

did i miss something?

Comment: Is the remote source hosted on the same domain? Can you open it in the browser? Does it contain valid datum objects?

Answer (score 0):

This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18100143) may be what you are looking for. I would also strongly recommend moving away from mysql_query and switch to something like PDO statements.

As llundin pointed out, have you made sure that the remote path is on the same domain? Are you able to open this URL in a browser with the g parameter filled out and get a response?

Comment: thanks Kyle, Ilundin, problem solved, you both save my day :)