# typeaheadjs: How to call server without using cached data

Tags: javascript, typeahead, typeahead.js

I am using typeaheadjs and fetching data using remote. When I type 'A' it fetches data starting with 'A', but next time when I delete and retype 'A' it shows data from cache. But I need to call the server every time without reusing the previous response.

Here is my code

```
    $('#demo').typeahead({
    remote: {
        url: '/Home/GetSuggestions?query=%QUERY&url=%URL',
        replace: function (url, query) {
            return url.replace('%QUERY', query).replace('%URL', 'http://www.example.com');
        },
    },
    minLength: 1,
    limit: 10,
    cache: false,
    valueKey: 'Key'
}).bind('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/UpdateTags/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(some_data),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#demo').typeahead('setQuery', '');
        }
    });
});
```

I have got the idea of adding minLength from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084408/how-to-use-typeahead-js-with-a-large-database). Am I missing anything?
Eagerly waiting for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the cache boolean inside the remote, that should do the trick

```
remote: {
    url: '/Home/GetSuggestions?query=%QUERY&url=%URL',
    replace: function (url, query) {
        return url.replace('%QUERY', query).replace('%URL', 'http://www.example.com');
    },
    cache: false
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking into the code base, an old trick might help here: add a cache-buster. In your `replace` function add a `_=randomdigits` which will make the url unique every time, preventing caching if caching is done per-url.