# Results from MySQL database using PHP not displaying when using Twitter typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, twitter, typeahead.js

I'm trying to integrate twitter typeahead with a web application. I have a MySQL database that I want to query every time the user enters something into the input field. I have done a fair amount of scavenging but I haven't figured out why the code isn't working. I have already visited this question:

[How to use typeahead.js with a large database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084408/how-to-use-typeahead-js-with-a-large-database/18100143#18100143)

Here's the typeahead script in my `index.php` file:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#ticker').typeahead({
        name: 'ticker',
        remote: 'app/scripts/suggest.php?query=%QUERY',
        limit: 5
    });
    console.log("Typeahead started");
})
</script>
```

The console.log is firing.

`suggest.php`:

```
 <?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");
if (isset($_REQUEST['query'])) {
    $query = $_REQUEST['query'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE field LIKE '%{$query}%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $array[] = array (
            'val1' => $row['val1'],
            'val2' => $row['val2'],
            'val3' => $row['val3']
        );
    }
    //RETURN JSON ARRAY
    echo json_encode ($array);
}

?>
```

The results from `suggest.php` are not showing up in the input field in my index.php page.

If I navigate to `localhost/app/scripts/suggest.php?query={val}`, the page populates with rows from the database in an array. So I am not sure what is wrong with it.